# Check value of boost::python::tuple for None

Tags: python, c++, boost

I'm trying to check whether a value in a boost::python::tuple is None. I have the following code:

```
namespace py = boost::python;

py::list ls(inf.Module().attr("data_out"));

for (int i = 0; i < len(ls); i++){     
    py::tuple tuple = py::extract<py::tuple>(ls[i]);
    if (tuple[1] == py::object()){  /* Does not work */
        //do other stuff
    }
}
```

This gives me:

```
TypeError: No registered converter was able to produce a C++ rvalue of type unsigned int from this Python object of type NoneType
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I have almost no experience with Boost.Python, but [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/FAQ#How_can_I_check_returning_Python_value_for_None.3F) seems appropriate. If it works for you, please create an answer yourself.